# addFilePattern does not throw FileNotFoundException if file to be added is not present

Tags: java, git, jgit

I have written a java program to push to a git repository where I am pushing specific files at a time instead of pushing all files.

```
try {
  git.add().addFilePattern("files\\file1.txt").call();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But if `file1.txt` is not present, the catch block is not entered.
If I do the same thing with CLI Git, it gives exception as

```
fatal: pathspec 'D:\mygit\files\\file1.txt' did not match any files
```

I want to catch this exception in Java using JGit.

JGit version 4.6.0, Java 1.8, Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JGit does not consider it as an error to pass a non-existing path `addFilepatern()`. The reason, therefore, could be that the method also accepts a file name pattern. And such a pattern may or may not match files.

You will have to check the existence of the file yourself. Either with the Java file API, for example

```java
boolean fileExists = new File( repository.getWorkTree(), "file.txt" ).isFile();
```

Or through the `DirCache` returned from `AddCommand::call()`, for example

```java
DirCache dirCache = git.add().addFilePattern( "file.txt" ).call();
boolean fileExists = dircache.findEntry( "file.txt" ) >= 0;
```